Adding search and pagination issue, financial dashboard tutorial, chapter 11
I've had to find different ways of getting through the tutorial, such as seeding my postgres database with my deployed app as opposed to through my local database, leaving me stuck having to code from the github UI over VS code.
It's been good so far, following each instruction again, as usual, console logs report the data they should. Upon getting to the point where I my page should be able to search the seeded data, I get an error on github that came from vercels' redeployment that failed, stating:
x 'import', and 'export' cannot be used outside of module code
,-[/vercel/path0/app/dashboard/invoices/page.tsx:17:1]
https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination
I understand that not all concepts in this tutorial have reached complete stability yet... am hoping for guidance and assistance in how I can troubleshoot this issue, if anyone else has faced and overcome it?
I've visited different forums that don't get to the specifics of my issue as they talk about different projects, though they have similar errors. The techniques they use apply to their projects as mine is specifically just the particular section of pagination and search functionality.
Here is the code of the 2 files giving error to the whole project:
//
import Pagination from '@/app/ui/invoices/pagination';
import Search from '@/app/ui/search';
import Table from '@/app/ui/invoices/table';
import { CreateInvoice } from '@/app/ui/invoices/buttons';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import { fetchLatestInvoices} from '@/app/lib/data';
import { Suspense } from 'react';

export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams?: {
    query?: string;
    page?: string;
  };
}) {
  const query = searchParams?.query || '';
  const currentPage = Number(searchParams?.page) || 1;
 
export default async function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
        <h1 className={`${lusitana.className} text-2xl`}>Invoices</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between gap-2 md:mt-8">
        <Search placeholder="Search invoices..." />
        <CreateInvoice />
      </div>
      {  <Suspense key={query + currentPage} fallback={<InvoicesTableSkeleton />}>
        <Table query={query} currentPage={currentPage} />
      </Suspense> }
      <div className="mt-5 flex w-full justify-center">
        { <Pagination totalPages={totalPages} /> }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

//
//
'use client';

import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Search({ placeholder }: { placeholder: string }) {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const pathname = usePathname();
  const { replace } = useRouter();
  function handleSearch(term: string) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
        if (term) {
      params.set('query', term);
    } else {
      params.delete('query');
    }
        replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
    console.log(term);
  }
  return (
    <div className="relative flex flex-1 flex-shrink-0">
      <label htmlFor="search" className="sr-only">
        Search
      </label>
      <input
        className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleSearch(e.target.value);
        }}
          defaultValue={searchParams.get('query')?.toString()}
      />
      <MagnifyingGlassIcon className="absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />
    </div>
  );
}

//

First, you need to label the files in your question. I'm assuming the first listing is app/dashboard/invoices/page.tsx.
In that file you have export default async function Page() inside the body of another export default async function Page().
This is clearly a cut/paste error.
Replace the second export default async function Page() with:
const totalPages = await fetchInvoicesPages(query);,
since the body of the function is referencing totalPages.
In fact, you need to include an import statement at the top of page.tsx as well:
import { fetchInvoicesPages } from '@/app/lib/data';
